# Proving that the intersection of a locally finite collection of open sets is empty

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that if $\{A_{i}\}$ for an arbitrary indexing set is a [locally finite collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection) of open sets, then $\bigcap_{i} A_{i}$ is empty.

I understand that given a point in the space this point won't be in this intersection. This is because for a given point $x$ in the space, we'll have a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $A_{i} \cap V \neq \emptyset$ for only a finite number of $i$'s. This means there will be infinitely many $A_i's$ that don't overlap with $V$ (therefore can't contain $x$).

But why wouldn't there be any points at all in this intersection? Is it because the given point is arbitrary and we can play this same game for all points in the space?

Comment: Yes to both, thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the indexing set need to be infinite? If it is finite, the claim is false.

Comment: I say arbitrary to include infinite and uncountable. You're right, if the index set is finite then there's not much to talk about.

Comment: Under this infiniteness hypothesis, you proved $\forall x\in X\quad x\notin\bigcap_iA_i.$ So the intersection is empty, period.